# Viewing MapInfo .MRR rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, multi-resolution-raster

I'd like to view MapInfo Multi Resolution Raster (.MRR) in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro.

[Esri Supported Rasters in ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm)

I've found zero methods to view mrr. I'm not keen to export to a different format. I'm going to submit an enhancement request to Esri Inc.

Comment: I doubt you are going to see support for that given it's a closed format from MapInfo...

Comment: The boss has approached Esri Premium support for the official word. I'll post the reply if it comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official word from Esri Inc technical support, is that Esri have no plans to support the .MRR format in their core products. If you want to view this format in ArcGIS you might try the Data Interop extension.